# ReactJS: Какова правильная реализация polling из компонента?

Tags: reactjs

Задался вопросом регулярного получения данных с сервера. На хабре нашел как реализовать polling: в компонент добавляется пара методов:

```
loadNewDataFromServer: function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
componentDidMount: function() {
    this.loadNewDataFromServer();
    setInterval(this.loadNewDataFromServer, this.props.pollInterval);
  }
```

**Вопрос 1:** Я правильно понимаю, перед удалением компонента из DOM (при переключении внимания пользователя на другой компонент, полностью не зависящий от полученных данных) для экономии трафика нужно прекратить запросы следующим образом:

```
componentWillUnmount(){

    // подскажите, что здесь?

  }
```

**Вопрос 2:** м.б., какие-то другие методы обновления данных на клиенте посоветуете?

Заранее, спасибо.

Comment: сохраните идентификатор таймера `this.timer = setInterval(...`, в  componentWillUnmount() остановите этот таймер `clearInterval( this.timer)`.

Comment: Идеологически есть два основных подхода. Подход 1: держать эту логику в хранилищах (если вы работаете с реактом, то какое-то типа-flux хранилище вам скорее всего понадобится). Поход 2: держать эту логику во вьюхах топ уровня, которые по сути скорее "вью контроллеры".

Comment: Другие методы: лонг-полл, вебсокеты. Для большинства задач сейчас лучше сокеты.

Comment: В componentWillUnmount нужно обязательно сделать clearInterval, иначе вы будете вызывать setState для несуществущего компонента (в dev режиме выскочит warning).

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете использовать для этого react-timer-mixin, он сам скинет setInterval при удалении компонента.

```
import React from 'react';
import TimerMixin from 'react-timer-mixin';

const Example = React.createClass({
  mixins: [TimerMixin],

  loadNewDataFromServer() {
    // ...
  },

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setInterval(this.loadNewDataFromServer, this.props.pollInterval);
  },
});
```